# Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED. (no capitals in package)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

So you can see there are no capitals in the package name. Previously, it said the user wasn't giving permission to install. Funny thing is the app was already installed and I was testing some new code. It asked to uninstall, I did, still not working. I restarted my device (Redmi Note 3, latest OS update) and then it gave this error. Worth noting that this app has given be trouble before as well. Device has API 23, I set the minSdkVersion to 23 but while clicking Run, it continued to show minSdkVersion as 28. I set it to 21, then ran it. Set it back to 23 and this time there was no trouble. Strange.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.nocapitals.www.nocapitals_hereeither">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SetReminder"/>
    <receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver" android:process="remote"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This probably won't fix anything, but what happens if you change your process name to `:remote`?

Comment: @TheWanderer That did it! But don't understand how? Is that the only correct way to do it?

Comment: It might have to do with permissions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element

Comment: @TheWanderer got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your process name to `:remote`.

I'm not completely sure why this works, but according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element), without the colon that process is global (shared by any app with the same UID as yours), and MIUI being MIUI may have blocked that from working.